# Read a number with zeros on left in Java

Tags: java

I need to read a number like '00123' including the '0's on the left side.
I used this snippet:

```
public class Solution 
{
      public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        long n=sc.nextLong(); //input: 00123
        System.out.println(n);//output: 123
      }
}
```

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: A *number* does not have zeroes on the left.  A *string of digits* might.  Don't confuse a "number" with a "representation of a number".

Comment: Why is this tagged with `c`?

Comment: Change n to String. ---> `String n = sc.next();`

Comment: There's no question here. Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Your requirements are simply contradicting. The number types in Java (or any other language) do not preserve leading zeros. Only strings do.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep the `0`(s) then you can't read it as a `long` (or any other primitive type). If that is your actual requirement, then you should store it (and read it) as a `String`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String n = sc.next();
System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: Thank you, @ElliottFrish . But I need it in integer data type.

Comment: @new_learner There is no integer data type that preserves leading zeros. Consider needing something else. An `int` is **always** 32-bits, a `long` is always 64-bits, a `char` is 16-bits and a `byte` is 8.

Comment: @new_learner what is the reason you need it as `integer`? Numbers do not have leading zeroes by concept. However you can save both representations, a `String` variant with leading zeroes (number is interpreted as text) and an `integer` variant without the zeroes for further computation. Tell us what you do with that number, it is likely that there is a better way for solving your issue.

Comment: @new_learner The integer data types all store numbers.  But you're asking for something more - a number _plus_ an indication of some leading zeroes.  You just don't _get_ that in an integer data type.  So it'll have to be some other data type, such as `String`.

Answer (score -2):

String.format("%05d", yournumber);

Comment: I don't think that this is what he wants

Comment: I think the problem is to output the same number of zeroes that the program saw on input, not to output exactly 5 digits.

Comment: And also, you should expand your answers a bit. Add some text, what is your code supposed to do etc.